# React component not updated when state accessed within return?

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here..

I am following the [Official React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). The following code is the working version as shown in the tutorial itself:

```
class Square extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="square"
                    onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
                {this.props.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

class Board extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null)
        };
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
        return (
            <Square
                value={this.state.squares[i]}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: X';

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        this.setState(
            () => {
                const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
                squares[i] = 'X';
                this.setState({squares: squares});
            }
        );
    }
}
```

To summarise, `Board` renders 9 `Squares` and passes a callback function to the `Square`, which updates the `state` of the `Board`.

The code above works just fine, and when I click on any of the `Square`s, its value is updated to `X`.

However, I made a mistake following the tutorial and actually implemented the `render` and `renderSquare` methods in `BoardComponent` as follows:

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square
            value={i}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        />
    );
}

render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[0])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[1])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[2])}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[3])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[4])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[5])}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[6])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[7])}
                {this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[8])}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The change is in the `Board#renderSquare` method and how it is called from the `Board#render`.

This change breaks the functionality and the value of the `Square`s being click on does not get updated.

To my eyes there should not be any difference between the 2 implementations but clearly I am missing something. Why is moving `this.state.squares[]` to `render` method break the functionality?

Comment: Nothing sticks out immediately as being different. I think there might be another problem in the rest of the code.

Comment: @xiiishaneiiix Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that any `this.state.squares[n]` can be `null` or `X`.

In your code you do this:

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square
            value={i}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        />
    );
}
```

```
{this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[n])}
```

You pass to `renderSquare` the *value*, instead of the index. `i` in `renderSquare` is `null` or `X`. Meaning that `handleClick` doesn't know what to change, because it expect an index instead.

Comment: I do not see any difference in your proposed code and the code I have which does not work.

Comment: Didn't pass you the correct version of the code. What I pass you is the explanation of why your code doesn't work. `this.handleClick(i)` doesn't work as you expect, because `i` is not an index, in your example. And `handleClick` expect an index. An index is a 0...n value. What you pass is the value ( `null` ). `null` !== 0...n.

Comment: `this.state.squares` is an array. If you want to modify the second value, `this.state.squares[1] = 'something'` is what you want do to. `1` is to be replaced with `i`. _Your i is not an array's index_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the `renderSquare(i)`.

On `this.renderSquare(this.state.squares[0])`, you passing `null` to `renderSquare` method.

In order to rerender your component, you need to define a new state which is different from the previous one, but:

```js
  handleClick(i) {
    this.setState(() => {
      const squares = [...this.state.squares];
      squares[i] = "X";                      //  <-- i is null
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const newState = { squares: squares };
        console.log(prevState);
        console.log(newState);
        console.log(prevState === newState);  // <-- true so no rerender. 
        return newState;
      });
    });
  }
```

To fix it define values for `state.squares` in the `constructor`

```js
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      squares: [...Array(9)].map((_, i) => i)
    };
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
  }
```

Check out this example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z334rl1np3?fontsize=14).

Comment: But I do not want to set values to initial state. It is totally fine that they start with null.

Comment: Ok so you need to fix `renderSquare` anyways, your `handleClick` is broken and that's why _moving this.state.squares[] to render method break the functionality_, it is only one of the possible fixes.